# Найти одинаковые члены указанных столбцов в массиве и обнулить, если нет обнулить указанные столбцы.Не работает обнуление и вывод конечной матрицы

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static int n;
    static int s;
    static int p;
    static int q;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите количество строк массива: ");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0 || n >= 15) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное числострок ");
        }
        System.out.print("Введите количество столбцов массива: ");
        s = scanner.nextInt();
        if (s <= 0 || s >= 15) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное число столбцов");
        }

        int mass[][] = new int[n][s];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < s; t++) {
                System.out.println("Введите " + (i + 1) + "-е " + "число " + (t + 1) + "-го столбца: ");
                mass[i][t] = scanner.nextInt();

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < s; t++) {
                System.out.print(mass[i][t] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Введите столбец №1, который нужно сравнить: ");
        p = scanner.nextInt();
        if (p > s || p <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неверный столбец");
        }
        System.out.println("Введите столбец №2, который нужно сранвить: ");
        q = scanner.nextInt();
        if (q > s || q <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неверный столбец");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; n++) {
            if (mass[i][p] == mass[i][q]) {
                mass[i][p] = 0;
                mass[i][q] = 0;
            } else {
                for (int c = 0; c < s; c++) {
                    mass[i][с] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < s; y++) {
                System.out.print(mass[u][y] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите весь лишний код и подробно распишите в чем проблема и на каких входных данных она возникает.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < n; n++) {
>     if (mass[i][p] == mass[i][q]) {
>         mass[i][p] = 0;
>         mass[i][q] = 0;
>     } else {
>         for (int c = 0; c < s; c++) {
>             mass[i][с] = 0;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Проблема в этом куске, а именно в `else` - он выполнится на первом же неравном значении, т. е. столбцы зануляются всегда. Тут надо оставить только then-часть, в ней порставить флаг, было ли найдено совпадеие и в соответствии с этим флагом уже после цикла обнулить весь столбец.

> ```
> System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное ...
> ```

Этот косяк к вопросу не относится, но после вывода сообщения об ошибке программа пордолжает выполняться с неверным значением. Вероятно, надо добавить return.